# Angular 10: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-date-picker/date-picker.module'

Tags: angular10

https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker

On Angular 10:
Installed:
`npm install ng2-date-picker --save`

Added to app.module: **(Full app.module)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DpDatePickerModule} from 'ng2-date-picker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DpDatePickerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Serve or Build:

```
ng serve
ng build
```

Got an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng2-date-picker/date-picker.module'
```

Any clue?

Comment: Can you share your full app.module file?

Comment: @abney317 I updated the question with full app.module code.

Comment: You didn't import the module

Comment: Oh sorry, copied from the wrong module file, I edited and fixed the question.